# Why does my font-size change when I revisit the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

For some reason on my mobile menu the font-size of links changes when i revisit the page. I have another page that uses the exact same javascript and CSS and the font size of the links does not change when you revist, taht page does not have iframes, so I'm assuming it's linked with the fact the page where the font  size changes has iframes

It does not change when i test it using dev tools on a browser but when testing on my Iphone X it does seem to change i'll attach a video of this where you can see when I revist the page the font sizer appears smaller and when clicking on one of the links padding or margin seems to increase
for some reason

Here is the video in the form of a gif file
https://giphy.com/gifs/RMGsA6Dg4Y9p6IvE4E

```
var iframes = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
var form = document.getElementsByTagName('form');
function toggleMobileMenu(){
//show menu
if(document.getElementById("testingdrop").style.visibility != "visible"){
    document.getElementById("testingdrop").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("testingdrop").style.transition = "0.5s";
    document.getElementById("testingdrop").style.width = "55%";
    document.getElementById("dropdownIcon").style.color = "#ffc800";
    //get all iframes elements and change opacity
    for(var i=0; i<frames.length; i++){
        iframes[i].style.opacity = "0.5";
    }
}
//hide menu
else{
    document.getElementById("testingdrop").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("testingdrop").style.width = "200%";
    document.getElementById("dropdownIcon").style.color = "black";
    for(var i=0; i<frames.length; i++){
        iframes[i].style.opacity = "1";
    }
}
}
```

HTML

```
   <div class="dropdown" id="testingdrop">
   <ul>
            <a href="./Home.html" class="mobilemenu"><li>HOME</li></a>
            <a href="./videos.html" class="mobilemenu"><li>VIDEOS</li></a>
            <a href="./enquiry.html" class="mobilemenu"><li>ENQUIRIES</li></a>
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/thegreatmurshed/" class="mobilemenu"><li>INSTAGRAM</li></a>
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/umarmiahfarooq/" class="mobilemenu" id="devBy"><li id="debByListItem">A WEBSITE BY <br>@UMARMIAHFAROOQ</li></a>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#testingdrop{
  visibility: hidden;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 55% auto;
  grid-template-rows: 29em;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: 0.5s;
  width: 200%;
}
li{
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  padding-left: 4px;
  left: -11.4%;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  z-index: 2;
}
ul{
  width: 100%;
  left: 3px;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  padding-bottom: 560%;
  padding-right: 82%;
  background: white/*#171717*/;
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  z-index: 2;
}
.mobilemenu{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  z-index: 2;
}
#devBy{
  color: #ffc800;
  font-size: 40%;
  z-index: 2;
}
#debByListItem{
  margin-top: 10%;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks all fine. maybe you've missed some style:

```js
var iframes = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
var form = document.getElementsByTagName("form");

function toggleMobileMenu() {
  //show menu

  if (document.getElementById("testingdrop").style.visibility != "visible") {
    document.getElementById("testingdrop").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("testingdrop").style.transition = "0.5s";
    document.getElementById("testingdrop").style.width = "55%";
    document.getElementById("dropdownIcon").style.color = "#ffc800";
    //get all iframes elements and change opacity
    for (var i = 0; i < frames.length; i++) {
      iframes[i].style.opacity = "0.5";
    }
  } else {
    //hide menu
    document.getElementById("testingdrop").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("testingdrop").style.width = "200%";
    document.getElementById("dropdownIcon").style.color = "black";
    for (var i = 0; i < frames.length; i++) {
      iframes[i].style.opacity = "1";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#testingdrop {
  visibility: hidden;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 55% auto;
  grid-template-rows: 29em;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: 0.5s;
  width: 200%;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  padding-left: 4px;
  left: -11.4%;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  transition: margin-left 0.5s;
  z-index: 2;
}

ul {
  width: 100%;
  left: 3px;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  padding-bottom: 560%;
  padding-right: 82%;
  background: white;
  transition: margin-left 0.5s;
  z-index: 2;
}

.mobilemenu {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  z-index: 2;
}

#devBy {
  color: #ffc800;
  font-size: 40%;
  z-index: 2;
}

#debByListItem {
  margin-top: 10%;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown" id="testingdrop">
  <ul>
    <a href="./Home.html" class="mobilemenu">
      <li>HOME</li>
    </a>
    <a href="./videos.html" class="mobilemenu">
      <li>VIDEOS</li>
    </a>
    <a href="./enquiry.html" class="mobilemenu">
      <li>ENQUIRIES</li>
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/thegreatmurshed/" class="mobilemenu">
      <li>INSTAGRAM</li>
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/umarmiahfarooq/" class="mobilemenu" id="devBy">
      <li id="debByListItem">A WEBSITE BY <br>@UMARMIAHFAROOQ</li>
    </a>
  </ul>
</div>

<a href="#" onclick="toggleMobileMenu()">Toggle Menu</a>
```